# Is there any way to catch unhandled application exceptions and log them

Tags: delphi, error-handling

is there any way to catch and log all errors in application. In the moment I use try catch blocks in places where I think error can occur. But is there a possibility to catch all errors in application level (I mean, can I put try catch block to project file or maybe some other trick will do it)?

Comment: You'd need to be able to define every conceivable type of error that would occur in your application and at what level, then surround them in try-catch blocks and/or log them somehow, like to the event log (assuming Windows) or a log file perhaps.

Comment: You can use the `TApplicationEvents` component and assign something to the `OnException` event. This procedure will then recieve all *unhandled* exceptions.

Comment: Why catch them? Usually you want to let them float up to the top level handler.

Comment: @David: It depends on the exception. If it's a result of a bug in your code, then yes; let it float up and be caught by your exception logger.  If it's a result of something outside your control, though, ("network connection not available," for example,) you want to find a way to handle it that doesn't throw an error dialog in the user's face and make it look like there's a bug in your code when there isn't.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to log all unhandled exceptions AND all handled exceptions?  You want to catch, and squelch (ignore) all exceptions? What exactly?

Answer (score 28):

Take a look at [MadExcept](http://madshi.net/madExceptDescription.htm).  If you add it into your project, it automatically installs hooks that will catch all unhandled exceptions, generate very informative error reports, and even email them to you or post them to a web service.  It's the next best thing to actually being able to attach the debugger to your clients' systems.

Answer (score 7):

You could also consider [Eureka Log](http://www.eurekalog.com/index_delphi.php), which CodeGear themselves [used for their PHP product](http://www.eurekalog.com/case0.php). Eureka Log also has memory leak detection and allows you to have crash reports silently emailed, ftp'd, added to a bug tracking system automatically, or allows interactive crash dump submission.

[image]

It isn't free, but I think it is *well* worth the money. I honestly couldn't imagine using Delphi without it. Also, they have a .NET edition of the program as well.

One last feature that I love, is that you can actually configure the product to take different actions with certain exceptions, while still capturing others normally. I use this with some of the Indy exceptions that can be thrown:

[image]

Comment: +1 for this.  We use EurekaLog at work. Its premium features are very useful, but a lot of the time MadExcept is "good enough," and it's free.

Comment: @Mason: MadExcept is only free for non-commercial applications. See: http://www.madexcept.com/madExceptShop.htm

Comment: @lkessler: Good catch.  I didn't even think of that distinction, because what I use it with *is* non-commercial.

Answer (score 2):

"Catching" an exception can mean many things: logging it, displaying it, acting on it, reraising it, or any combination of the above. The TApplication OnException handler will "catch" all unhandled main thread exceptions, but will not catch exceptions raised in threads. To do this you will need to implement your own thread exception handling. In my application framework (http://www.csinnovations.com/framework_overview.htm) I have code that will ensure that any exception can be logged (all unhandled exceptions and optionally any handled exceptions), and optionally displayed if it is in the main thread, regardless of whether it occurs in the main thread or any other thread. While it is not as comprehensive as MadExcept, it has all the functionality that is needed to handle exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to intercept ALL exceptions and log them, you need to implement a `RTLUnwindProc` low-level procedure.

This is a bit low-level (e.g. it needs asm skills), so you should better rely on existing code. See [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415242/is-there-a-way-to-catch-all-exceptions-even-those-handled-with-jcldebug).

I even put some reference code (including low-level asm, working with Delphi 7 and later under Win32) in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6415902/458259), which shows the [logging features included in our Open Source *mORMot* framework](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/04/14/Enhanced-logging-in-SynCommons). To log all exceptions, just add a reference to `SynCommons.pas` and add the following line at program startup:

```
TSynLog.Family.Level := [sllException,sllExceptionOS];
```

Currently working from Delphi 5 up to XE4, for both Win32 and Win64 platforms.

Answer (score -1):

use try..except block like this:

```
try
..
// a critical section here
..
except on E:exception do
begin
  showmessage('an error occured: ' + E.message);
  //do something else
end
end;
```

Comment: @Warren This young fellow caught an exception and showed a message :)

Comment: But one vote for a code sample!!! Nice to know for newones coming to search for exception handling...