# Application.OnException fails to handle all the exception - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm using Delphi 7 and in an attempt to handle all the possible exceptions being thrown during the run of the program. I used Application.OnException := HandlerProcedure; to handle exceptions but when exception occurs, HandlerProcedure never gets called. In order to assure if it really works, I raised exception after I assigned Application.OnException as below:

```
Application.OnException := HandlerProcedure;
raise Exception.Create('Exception');
```

and defined HandlerProcedure as:

```
procedure TFormMain.HandlerProcedure(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
    ShowMessage('Exception.');      
    Exit;
end;
```

But HandlerProcedure never gets called. How can I make it handle all the exceptions?

Comment: the different names  HandleImportScheduleException and HandlerProcedure do not exists in your real code ?

Comment: Please provide SSCCE. Most likely you are raising exception before `Application.Run`.

Comment: Oh. That doesn't exist in my real code though. Just edited the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I want to handle exceptions when I close main form as:

    procedure TFormMain.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);

Comment: We need an SSCCE. We cannot tell you what's wrong until you show code. Please provide an SSCCE. You should always do so when asking a question.

Comment: Seems you have a new favorite acronym :)

Comment: My guess is that he is jamming `Application.OnException := HandlerProcedure;` somewhere else then the project source file.

Comment: .. just in case it gets stuck ..

Comment: For those who have no idea what SSCCE is, look here: 

http://www.sscce.org/
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Answer (score 13):

If you want to intercept ALL exceptions, you need to implement a `RTLUnwindProc` low-level procedure.

This is a bit low-level (e.g. it needs asm skills), so you should better rely on existing code. See [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415242/is-there-a-way-to-catch-all-exceptions-even-those-handled-with-jcldebug). I even put some reference code (including low-level asm, working with Delphi 7 and later under Win32) in [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6415902/458259).

Comment: Most likely this poor advice. I expect that all that's needed is for asker to fix their bug so the OnException is called. At best this answer is misleading.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan OP wrote he was "*in an attempt to handle all the possible exceptions being thrown during the run of the program*"... sounds like if my answer fits with this question, doesn't it?

Comment: Asker surely doesn't understand the nuance that you are inferring

Comment: Down voting because of what you think the OP is potentially nuancing is pretty unfair. Googling about 'handle all exceptions of a Delphi program' will certainly point to this question. I'm sometimes fed up of SO down voters.

Comment: I personally think you should get +1 for trying to put useful information out there. +1 from me.

Answer (score 3):

Something is wrong in your code. The [example](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Forms_TApplication_OnException.html) from Embarcadero's website is working perfect.

```
{
In addition to displaying the exception message, which 
happens by default, the following code shuts down the 
application when an exception is not caught and handled.  
AppException should be declared a method of TForm1.
}
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Application.OnException := AppException;
end;

procedure TForm1.AppException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception);
begin
  Application.ShowException(E);
  Application.Terminate;
end; 

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  raise EPasswordInvalid.Create('Incorrect password entered');
end;
```

Also good practices on handling errors on Delphi are described [here](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/25665).
In order to further investigate the problem you have, you should take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259563/good-os-delphi-exception-handling-libraries

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a third party exception handler such as madExcept, Application.OnException no longer fires. You must instead code TMadExceptionHandler.OnException event or directly call RegisterExceptionHandler.